# What's an example of a string that's valid for URL(string:) but invalid for URLComponents(string:)?

Tags: swift, url, foundation, rfc3986

[Foundation's `URL(string:)` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) can fail if the string doesn't represent a URL as defined in RFC 1808.

[The `URLComponents(string:)` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) can fail if the string doesn't represent a URL as defined in RFC 3986.

What is an example of a string for which `URL(string:)` returns a `URL`, but for which `URLComponents(string:)` returns `nil`? (Is there a URL string that is valid according to RFC 1808 but invalid according to RFC 3986?)